# Nuxtjs data fetch using async fetch throws 500 error in docker container

Tags: docker, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I am getting 500 error on page refresh on pages with `async fetch`. If I navigate from one page to another the application runs fine, but if I do page refresh on async fetch pages then it throws 500 error.

I tried to diable SSR but then it shows a never ending loader, when I run the same code without a docker as `npm run dev` then no issues on page reload.

**My Dockerfile**

```
# Base image
FROM node:14

# Update the system packages and install required dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && apt-get install -y libglu1 \
    && apt-get install -y libxi6 libgconf-2-4 \
    && apt-get clean

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/frontend

WORKDIR /var/www/frontend

COPY package*.json .

# Copy the entire application to the container
COPY . .

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8001

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=8001

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev3"]
```

**My docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
    image: frontend
    container_name: frontend
    command: ["npm", "run", "dev3"]
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/frontend
      - /var/www/frontend/node_modules
```

below code in page/._vue file

```
async fetch(context) {
    try {

      await context.store.dispatch('page/get', {sample: false});

     } catch (e) {
        context.error({ statusCode: e.response ? e.response.status : 500 });
     }
}
```

In store/page.js

```
export const actions = {
    async get({ commit, getters, dispatch, rootGetters }) {

        let { data } = await this.$axios.get('page', {
            params: {
                url: this.app.context.route.fullPath
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On enabling debug mode in axios, I see below error:

```
[Axios] Response error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      connection: 'upgrade',
      'x-real-ip': '127.0.0.1',
      'x-forwarded-for': '127.0.0.1',
      'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
      'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
      referer: 'http://example.test/about-us',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
      cookie: '__stripe_mid=; _password=; __stripe_sid=',
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
    },
    baseURL: 'http://example.test/api',
    params: { url: '/about-us', fetch_menus: true },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'page',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/api/page?url=%2Fabout-us&fetch_menus=true',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: 'example.test',
      port: null,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/api/page',
      search: '?url=%2Fabout-us&fetch_menus=true'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /api/page?url=%2Fabout-us&fetch_menus=true HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'connection: upgrade\r\n' +
        'x-real-ip: 127.0.0.1\r\n' +
        'x-forwarded-for: 127.0.0.1\r\n' +
        'cache-control: max-age=0\r\n' +
        'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1\r\n' +
        'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\r\n' +
        'referer: http://example.test/about-us\r\n' +
        'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n' +
        'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n' +
        'cookie: __stripe_mid=; _password=; __stripe_sid=\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Host: example.test\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/api/page?url=%2Fabout-us&fetch_menus=true',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'example.test',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http://example.test/api/page?url=%2Fabout-us&fetch_menus=true',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Comment: Any error message in the 500 error?

Comment: @RobinThomas I have shared the error above thrown by axios.